# PySpark pairwise distance between row

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, correlation, pairwise-distance

Now I am working with PySpark, and wondering is there a way to do pairwise distance between row. For instance, there is a dataset like this.

```
+--------------------+------------+--------+-------+-------+
|             product| Mitsubishi | Toyota | Tesla | Honda |
+--------------------+------------+--------+-------+-------+
|Mitsubishi          |           0|     0.8|    0.2|      0|
|Toyota              |           0|       0|      0|      0|  
|Tesla               |         0.1|     0.4|      0|    0.3|
|Honda               |           0|     0.5|    0.1|      0|
+--------------------+------------+--------+-------+-------+
```

I'm curious, because in pandas I used this line of code using `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances
array = df1_corr.drop(columns=['new_product_1']).values
correlation = pairwise_distances(array, array, metric = 'correlation')
```

How about PySpark, is there any built in `pairwise_distance` on it? or in `sparkml`?

Answer (score 0):

The way to go with your problems is pandas_udf. Here is a good read and examples similar to your scenario.

https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/30/introducing-vectorized-udfs-for-pyspark.html

https://towardsdatascience.com/scalable-python-code-with-pandas-udfs-a-data-science-application-dd515a628896